# Block characters: textbox cpp

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio-2012

I have a form that contains a textbox(c++ visual studio 2012).

my question is, how do I block a character/symbol into the textbox?

Comment: Which UI framework are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @chris i use CLR framework sir

Comment: If you mean the Common Language Runtime, then you should tag the question with the specific dialect of C++ you're using because standard C++ doesn't run on CLR. In addition, all of WinForms, WPF, and WinRT integrate with the CLR, so it's still a guess at which UI framework it is.

Comment: Actually, I found out that MSVC supports compiling unmanaged C++ for the CLR with just a compiler switch, so the language tag might be fine after all.